# please refer my following code.i want to display data in view by using ajax but i get error[obect object]]

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

This is my controller here I get data no problem.

```
public function getSupplierByID(){$supplier_id = $this->input->post('supplier_id');
        if($supplier_id !=''){
            $data= $this->Supplier_model->getSupplierByid($supplier_id);
            echo json_encode($data);
         }
    }
```

This is my `javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sel_supplier_name').change(function () {
        var supplier = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/get/supplier'; ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: "supplier_id=" + supplier,
            datatype: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                //exit();
                alert($('#txt_contact_perName').val(data.contact_prsn_name));
                );
        });
    });
});
```

This is what I get in response.

```
[{"supp_id":"2","supplier_id":"3","products_id":"5","company_id":"5","power":"25","quantity":"300","rate":"52","min_level":"20","max_level":"200","CGST":"5%","SGST":"5%","total":"10000","added_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","prefix":"Mr.","first_name":"abc","middle_name":"balaso","last_name":"tanugade","gender":"Male","contact_no":"123456789","email_id":"sangram@gmail.com","contact_prsn_name":"ssss","contact_prsn_no":"9158424290","address_line1":"por","address_line2":"xyz","country_id":"0","state_id":"0","city_id":"0","postal_code":"0","product_name":"EMLA cream","company_name":"Hindustan Antibiotics"},{"supp_id":"2","supplier_id":"3","products_id":"5","company_id":"5","power":"25","quantity":"300","rate":"52","min_level":"20","max_level":"200","CGST":"5%","SGST":"5%","total":"10000","added_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","prefix":"Mr.","first_name":"abc","middle_name":"balaso","last_name":"tanugade","gender":"Male","contact_no":"123456789","email_id":"sangram@gmail.com","contact_prsn_name":"ssss","contact_prsn_no":"9158424290","address_line1":"por","address_line2":"xyz","country_id":"0","state_id":"0","city_id":"0","postal_code":"0","product_name":"EMLA cream","company_name":"Acadia Pharmaceuticals"}]
```

when I alert I get `[object object]` error.
Please give me solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `[object object]` on `alert(data);` because data is an array of objects.

The data has 2 elements and you can loop each elements by using `.forEach`

Like:

```
data.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log( v["contact_prsn_name"] );  
});
```

To access the first element of the array, You can

```
alert( data[0]["contact_prsn_name"] );
```

---

Snippet of the loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
    "supp_id": "2",
    "supplier_id": "3",
    "products_id": "5",
    "company_id": "5",
    "power": "25",
    "quantity": "300",
    "rate": "52",
    "min_level": "20",
    "max_level": "200",
    "CGST": "5%",
    "SGST": "5%",
    "total": "10000",
    "added_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "updated_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "prefix": "Mr.",
    "first_name": "abc",
    "middle_name": "balaso",
    "last_name": "tanugade",
    "gender": "Male",
    "contact_no": "123456789",
    "email_id": "sangram@gmail.com",
    "contact_prsn_name": "ssss",
    "contact_prsn_no": "9158424290",
    "address_line1": "por",
    "address_line2": "xyz",
    "country_id": "0",
    "state_id": "0",
    "city_id": "0",
    "postal_code": "0",
    "product_name": "EMLA cream",
    "company_name": "Hindustan Antibiotics"
  }, {
    "supp_id": "2",
    "supplier_id": "3",
    "products_id": "5",
    "company_id": "5",
    "power": "25",
    "quantity": "300",
    "rate": "52",
    "min_level": "20",
    "max_level": "200",
    "CGST": "5%",
    "SGST": "5%",
    "total": "10000",
    "added_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "updated_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "prefix": "Mr.",
    "first_name": "abc",
    "middle_name": "balaso",
    "last_name": "tanugade",
    "gender": "Male",
    "contact_no": "123456789",
    "email_id": "sangram@gmail.com",
    "contact_prsn_name": "ssss",
    "contact_prsn_no": "9158424290",
    "address_line1": "por",
    "address_line2": "xyz",
    "country_id": "0",
    "state_id": "0",
    "city_id": "0",
    "postal_code": "0",
    "product_name": "EMLA cream",
    "company_name": "Acadia Pharmaceuticals"
  }];

  //This is how you update the div
  data.forEach(function(v) {
    $("#txt_contact_perName").append(v.contact_prsn_name);
    $("#txt_contact_perName").append("<br />");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txt_contact_perName"></div>
```

Comment: I am new in ajax so please help me.can you please explain how do I use in javascript and I also display the data I get from database into form.

Comment: What data do you want to display?

Comment: The data which I get in controller, I want to display in view using ajax.

Comment: Please check  the new code snippet, Currently it loops and update the div with id `txt_contact_perName`

Comment: You have to use a loop because you are returning 2 values on the array

Comment: How do wirte in success in javascript?

Comment: You already have a success function. You just have to update it.

Comment: I got solution I have use following code success: function (data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(obj, function (key, element) {
                        $('#txt_contact_perName').val(element.contact_prsn_name);
                        
                    });  thanks for your help